# Cant access properties returned by Angulars $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

Im trying to fetch data with angulars resource factory, but I don't quite understand how to process the responce properly.

The factory:

```
function dataFactory($resource, ENV) {
  return $resource('http://foo/bar', {
      accountId: '@accountId'
    },
    {
      getData: {
        method: 'POST',
         url: 'http://foo/bar',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

      }
    }
  );
}
```

In the service:

```
     function fetchRealTimeData() {
        return dataFactory.getData(requestParameters).$promise;

  }
```

In my directive:

```
dataToApply = CdnAnalyticsService.fetchRealTimeData()
```

When I log dataToApply, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

I can't use regular object notation to access the properties,returns undefined.

How can I access the properties on the returned object?

Answer (score 0):

Your resource is returning a promise. You need to resolve that promise to access the returned data.

```
function fetchRealTimeData () {
  return dataFactory.getData(requestParameters)
    .then(function (data) {
      return data;
    });
}
```

The way that you're doing it, you're returning the actual promise object, not the resolved data from the promise. The reason you can see the data in the console is because it's resolved by the time that it logs out, but when you try to access it with dot notation, the promise still hasn't resolved and you get undefined.